# How to Use a custom FormAuthenticator

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web.xml, context.xml

```
package myPackage;   
 public class MyFormAuthenticator extends FormAuthenticator{

    //code lies here
    }
```

Web.xml file

```xml
<web-app>
   ...
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/securedfile.jsp</jsp-file>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/secured</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>SecuredBookSite</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/secured/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
      </web-resource-collection>

      <auth-constraint>
         <description>Let only managers use this app</description>
         <role-name>employee</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
   </security-constraint>

   <security-role>
      <role-name>employee</role-name>
   </security-role>

   <login-config>
      <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
      <form-login-config>
         <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
         <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
      </form-login-config>
   </login-config>
   ...
</web-app>
```

I Read that context.xml file should be edited for any-non default uses. but i don't know how . I'm just started in tomcat so i don't really know to use it .
can you give some explanation about the working of FormAuthenticator.

I tried like this

```
context.xml

<Context docBase="Form_Auth1">
<Valve className  ="myPackage.MyFormAuthenticator"/>

</Context>
```

iam compiling java class using cmd .
Tomcat version:8.5
Roles are defined in Tomcat-users.xml

please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: any solution to this? I have same issue